# WaitForMultipleObjects with a mutex and an event

Tags: c++, winapi, synchronization, mutex

If I have the following C++ code (for Windows Os):

```
HANDLE hEvent = ::CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
HANDLE hMutex = ::CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);

HANDLE hHandles[] = {
    hEvent,
    hMutex
};

DWORD dwR = ::WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hHandles, FALSE, INFINITE) - WAIT_OBJECT_0;

//if dwR == 0, what state is hMutex in?
//Or, do I need to call ReleaseMutex(hMutex) in that case?
```

I'm not sure how to handle this situation regarding the mutex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dwR` is not quite zero, it is `WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0`, that is your wait was satisfied on the first provided handle. This is event's handle, so you don't need to touch your mutex.

If result is `WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1` then it was mutex handle used to succeed in waiting. And once you are done with things you need to do, you release the ownership by calling `ReleaseMutex`.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I needed to know. And by the way, speaking of WAIT_OBJECT_0, I subtracted it before checking it.

Comment: Oh yes you did - sorry I missed that part.

Comment: Don't subtract it unconditionally like you are. `WaitForMultipleObject()` can return other error codes that `WAIT_OBJECT_0` should not be sutracted from. Only subtract it if `WaitForMultipleObjects()` returns either `WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0` or `WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1`, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The function works as the the WaitForSingleObject method on mutexes. There is an example in the MSDN ([MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) which illustrates acquiring a Mutex with the WaitForSingleObject. WaitForMultipleObjects has the same behavior while using a Mutex.

Comment: Yes, thanks. The single object is easy. My main concern here is not to create a "race condition" when event is signaled and mutex is left hanging, so to speak... But @RomanR above confirmed that I need to release mutex only when WaitForMultipleObjects returns its index.

Answer (score 0):

This was a good question. In any case, the Microsoft documentation is not so clear with this.

The documentation of WaitForMultipleObjects with bWaitAll = FALSE says: "If multiple objects become signaled, the function returns the index of the first handle in the array whose object was signaled."

But the documentation says also that "Modification occurs only for the object or objects whose signaled state caused the function to return", which makes sense, because otherwise we would not know whether also the Mutex would have been acquired.

According to my experiments, WaitForMultipleObjects does not acquire the "extra" mutex locks, which is good.